# How to clear all console logs from different runs in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have almost 10 running micro services, each printing their logs in console. for a specific reason, instead of traversing between console logs and hit clear button, I want to clear all once. Is there straightforward way?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO there is no way to clear all consoles at once. You can write your own plugin to do this.

Also note that you can traverse(loop through) each console just by clicking on console icon([image]) in the console view toolbar again and again. No need to use down arrow button of console icon then switch to each console then clear.